# How can I sort my list in selection sort not by index, but by numbers?

Tags: python, sorting

The question is just pure curiosity, since I quite  recently started learning algorithms and data structures and applying knowledge in python.
my code is:

```
def sorting(listik):
    n = range(len(listik))
    for i in n:
        lowest = min(listik[i:])
        for j in n:
            if listik[j] < listik[lowest:]:
                lowest, listik[j] = i, j

listik = [2,8,5,4,7,1,6,9,10,3]
sorting(listik)
print listik
```

output is correct, but it is sorted by indexes as it's supposed to.
I have seen codes that do that with for loop, but those were not selection sort algorithms, however i can't be 100% sure if this is possible applying this algorithm.(also, would love to hear a comment, if this algorithm could be simplified,w/o using external libraries tho)
Thank you !

Comment: I don't see any external libraries

Comment: @HarshithThota What I meant is in general if this specific code could be simplified(i don't know if that could be possible)

Comment: @pyjka could you specify your desired output for this example please ? and would you use predefined methods ?

Comment: Regarding code optimization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @HarshithThota [1,2,3,4,5..etc]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. There is nothing in your question to indicate that the accepted answer is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sort :

```
>>> listik = [2,8,5,4,7,1,6,9,10,3]
>>> listik.sort()
>>> listik
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in sorted function will sort the list of numbers, regardless of index.

```
print(sorted(listik))
```

Comment: He wants to simulate selection sort in Python, not simply sort a list.